# PyCharm incorrect code completion when using identical named fixtures across modules

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest, fixtures, pytest-fixtures

I've just started using pytest with PyCharm (version 2022.1.4) and am stumped on a pytest fixture / PyCharm code completion issue.

In this example, I have two modules `a.py` and `b.py` which are part of the same project. There is a fixture in `a.py` and another fixture in `b.py` both of which use the same name but do different things. The code completion / intellisense from PyCharm when I'm in `b.py` is giving me the class variable defined in `a.py` instead of what's defined in `b.py`.

It's my understanding that fixtures are not re-used throughout the project and are local to the module it's defined in.

What am I missing here? Can fixture names not be reused in other modules?

**a.py**

```
import pytest

class Person_A:
    name = "A"

@pytest.fixture()
def person():
    return Person_A()

def test_name(person):
    assert person.name == "A"
```

**b.py**

```
import pytest

class Person_B:
    age = 80

@pytest.fixture()
def person():
    return Person_B()

def test_age(person):
    assert person.  # <---- The code completion here after typing the "." only shows "name" from a.py
                    # also, hovering over the "person" parameter passed in shows that it's from a.py
```

In the code above I define a `person` fixture in both `a.py` and `b.py`. However, in `b.py` when I go and use the fixture in the function `test_age(person)` the code completion only gives me the ability to select 'name' (which is only defined in `a.py`). Also, in `b.py` if I hover over the `person` parameter passed in to the `test_age` function it's showing that it's from `a.py`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can add a type hint, that will certainly fix the issue. As for why it does not find it - without a type hint it is difficult, as PyCharm has to parse the function implementation to understand what is returned.

Comment: Thanks, adding a type hint does solve the issue. I was unsure originally if type hints are generally used with pytest since they aren't used anywhere in their documentation.